# c# Generics: Different Return Types using Generics

Tags: c#, generics, interface, return-type

I have a Data access library which I would like to return different data formats (XML, Json, DataTable).  I was trying to use Generics to achieve this.

```
public interface IDBInteractor<T>
{
    T ExecuteDSQuery(string myQuery)
}

public class DBInteractorDT : IDBInteractor<DataTable>
{
    public DataTable ExecuteDSQuery(string myQuery)
    {
        return new DataTable();
    }
}

public class DBInteractorJson : IDBInteractor<JsonString>
{
    public JsonString ExecuteDSQuery(string myQuery)
    {
        return new JsonString();
    }
}
```

I am having trouble invoking the correct method. Ideally I would to declare something like

```
     SomeClass<DataTable> dt = new SomeClass<DataTable>();
     SomeClass<JsonString> js = new SomeClass<JsonString>();

     DataTable myDT = dt.ExecuteDSQuery(myQuery);
     JsonString myJson = js.ExecuteDSQuery(myQuery);
```

I'm not sure how to declare SomeClass. I know I could do something like

```
    public class SomeClass<T> where T : IDBInteractor <T>
    {
        public T ExecuteQuery(T dtobject, string myQuery)
        {
           return dtobject.ExecuteDSQuery(myQuery);
        }
    }
```

But I don't want to have to pass an object instance (dtobject) to each method call.

Comment: Why `DBInteractorJson`'s `ExecuteDSQuery` returns string? It should return `JsonString`

Comment: Compare `SomeClass<DataTable> dt = new SomeClass<DataTable>();` and `public class SomeClass<T> where T : IDBInteractor <T>`. But `DataTable` is not an `IDBInteractor <T>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do? This code works fine:

```
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IDBInteractor<DataTable> dt = new SomeClass<DataTable>(new DBInteractorDT());
            IDBInteractor<JsonString> js = new SomeClass<JsonString>(new DBInteractorJson());
            /*
            or you can write 

            IDBInteractor<DataTable> dt = new DBInteractorDT();
            IDBInteractor<JsonString> js = new DBInteractorJson();

             */

            DataTable myDT = dt.ExecuteDSQuery("");
            JsonString myJson = js.ExecuteDSQuery("");
        }
    }

    public interface IDBInteractor<T>
    {
        T ExecuteDSQuery(string myQuery);
    }

    public class DBInteractorDT : IDBInteractor<DataTable>
    {
        #region IDBInteractor<DataTable> Members

        public DataTable ExecuteDSQuery(string myQuery)
        {
            return new DataTable();
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class DBInteractorJson : IDBInteractor<JsonString>
    {
        #region IDBInteractor<JsonString> Members

        public JsonString ExecuteDSQuery(string myQuery)
        {
            return new JsonString();
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class SomeClass<T> : IDBInteractor<T>
    {
        private IDBInteractor<T> interactor;

        public SomeClass(IDBInteractor<T> interactor)
        {
            this.interactor = interactor;
        }

        public T ExecuteDSQuery(string myQuery)
        {
            return interactor.ExecuteDSQuery(myQuery);
        }
    }

    public class JsonString
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, I was originally mistakenly invoking the object like: DBInteractorDT<DataTable> dt = new DBInteractorDT();

Answer (score 0):

if your generic parameter has a parameterless constructor you can create a new Object T();

but you have to define that your T has to have a parameterless constructor
use the generic constraint new() to force that:

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T : IDBInteractor <T> , new()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the new() constraint to your class definition so your class becomes:

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T : IDBInteractor <T>, new()
{
    public T ExecuteQuery(string myQuery)
    {
       return new T().ExecuteDSQuery(myQuery);
    }
}
```

You can then do any set up in a public parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SomeClass<T>` has an dependency on `IDBInteractor<T>`. You could add a `new()` constraint so you can create a instance in `SomeClass<T>` whenever you need one.

But why don't use the power of depencency injection? Just accept a `IDBInteractor<T>` as a parameter at the constructor of `SomeClass<T>`?

#### The code

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T : IDBInteractor <T>
{
    private IDBInteractor<T> _interactor;

    public SomeClass(IDBInteractor<T> interactor)
    {
        _interactor = interactor;
    }

    public T ExecuteQuery(string myQuery)
    {
       return _interactor.ExecuteDSQuery(myQuery);
    }
}
```

#### See also

http://www.theserverside.com/news/1321158/A-beginners-guide-to-Dependency-Injection

Answer (score 0):

I agree with  fix_likes_coding. If you only want to create a class to execute a query you may look at extension methods instead. This may not fit well in the scheme of things but might help if you wanted to keep things simple.

```
public static class InteractorUtils
{
    public static T ExecuteQuery(this IDBInteractor<T> interactor, string myQuery)
    {
        return interactor.ExecuteDSQuery(myQuery);
    }
}
```

and you could use it like this:

```
IDBInteractor<DataTable> dt = new DBInteractorDT();

dt.ExecuteQuery("");
```